# Load one JSON file in multiple functions jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I am currently trying to use one JSON file to load data onto my page. I have two arrays inside it of it:

```
{
"categories": [],
"cartItems": []
}
```

I have my data loading onto the page, but I call the JSON file each time that I am wanting to load the page, view item in modal, and then also loading it when an item is added to the cart.

```
function getData() {
    $.getJSON("data/data.json", function (data) {


    });

};
function modalData() {
        $.getJSON("data/data.json", function (data) {


        });

 };
function addtocart() {
        $.getJSON("data/data.json", function (data) {


        });

 };
```

Is there a simplier way to load the data and not call it each time I run a new function?

Comment: Does it call the same file each time?  Just call it once and cache the results

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution, you need to assign the output of the ajax request to a variable, which will be visible to all the corresponding function, where you will use this, hope this fixes your issue!

```js
var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
var dataMaster = function() {
  var tmp = null;
  $.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: root + '/posts/1',
    method: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
      tmp = data;
    }
  });
  return tmp;
}();


function modalData() {
  console.log(dataMaster.userId);
};
modalData();

function addtocart() {
  console.log(dataMaster.userId);
};
addtocart();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Katie Does this help you?